# Print dialog prints an empty sheet

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing

I'm using `PrintDialog` and `PrintDocument` controls to print the form. But when I click the Button, it always prints an empty sheet. I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you handling `PrintDocument1`'s events properly? It can't just automagically know what it is you want to print.

Comment: I want to print the entire form during running. I didn't handle anything

Comment: As in, a screenshot of the form, or data in your form, or ...?

Comment: [This is how it's supposed to be done.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx?cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) Also, try looking at the `ControlPaint` class for your screenshot. (And if you're still stuck, ask someone else, because I won't be back for 10 hours :P)

Comment: 1 more. I think it will print the file

Answer (score 0):

The actual printing takes place in the printdocument1.printpage event handler. To do this, you can output to the graphics object of the parameter PrintPageEventArgs in your PrintPage handler.

```
AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf printaPage
PrintDocument1.Print()

...

Sub printaPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
' output to e.Graphics here
...
```